Plasma 6, how to switch light/dark, when you're using a custom colour set?
In System Settings -> Global Theme, there are four entries and there does not seem to be a feature to select the current configuration as a new theme.
What if I am using a custom colour set (Settings -> Colours), that is not "Breeze Light/Dark"? How can I switch to light/dark mode with one click?
Currently, I would have to switch the theme and then manually select the custom colour set, which is cumbersome. And I don't understand why I can create a modified global theme with my custom colour set.

I have not tried with custom themes, but there is a Plasma widget what allows you to switch themes between two themes: https://store.kde.org/p/1804745
